Likely copy/pasting a dictionary in the comments: how should we respond?
Some questions (like this one) end up with comments which appear to have been copy/pasted from somewhere, and I'd guess from a dictionary.
While these users are trying to help, I see multiple problems with this:

it's largely effortless ["your answer is somewhere among this huge text you probably can't read"],
copyright/plagiarism issues,
comments are thought of as "temporary" (see below),
comments are not editable, nor downvote-able,
they may answer the question in the comments,
it can look like a total mess, sometimes requiring multiple comments,

What should we do in these circumstances?
Question: Likely copy/pasting a dictionary in the comments: how should we respond?
Comments are often described as "second-class citizens" on Stack Exchange:

Comments are second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not designed to hold information for all eternity
Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?

The help page explains what comments are for:

Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be upvoted (but not downvoted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.


I haven't searched exhaustively, but it's not hard to find many, many examples:

Obstructive amounts of text What is the difference between 本来 and 原来? 
Three comments in a row here: What's the difference between "现在几点？“ and "现在几点了？” and Difference between 不得不， 不免 and 必然?
Four comments in a row here: what is the difference between 條 and 匹? and What is the difference in usage between the pairs 依然/仍然 and 依旧/仍旧?
And the OP even complained:

I was interested in 然 and 旧. Please don't spam
Maria Efremova, 2017

Six comments here: Give further examples of morphological alternation patterns such as Verb/Noun (处 chu3 / chu4) and Active/Inactive Verb (好 hao4 / hao3)
Here How to use 者 as "... one who is ..."? the author was told

If you have questions or suggestions about how the community treats comments, please post a question on the meta site.
Don Kirkby ♦

This was subsequently ignored with arguing in the comments here: Why is it 出差去 and not 去出差?
More arguing in comments Difference between 必 and 一定 and Using xiànzài and zhèngzài in a single sentence and https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/29449/8099

This really is an obstructive misuse of comments.  I'm not sure why these are left unmoderated.

Those kinds of comments seem to come from one user.

For the sake of not starting a series of comments not relevant to the question, I think moderators have generally ignored that user's comments. That user tended to ask a series of why is my other comment with X upvotes not deleted, but this one was deleted? Someone clearly found it helpful as indicated by the number of upvotes, the moderator shouldn't have deleted them, I think that moderator has something against me, which are very difficult to deal with.

Maybe this is of interest: https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1587/4136

Thanks; I added an answer there.  But I still don't know what I should do when I see this happening.  I flagged this one recently, but the comments are still full of noise.

@Becky李蓓 Yeah, just flag them for now, they'll show up in the normal review queue if not in our mod review queue. I didn't see any flags show up for the comments in the question you linked above, but I just purged all the comments now. If you really need help with clearing up something you can contact one of us mods.
